# pandas optimizing bootstrapping

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to get the standard error of the weighted mean of some columns in a DF. I have the code down to the below, however for a DF of about 800k rows, this takes about 9 seconds, so I am wondering if there are any improvements I am missing that can shave of a significant amount of time, still

```
def bootstrap_se_mean(df: pd.DataFrame, cols:list, w, k=1000):
    res = np.zeros(shape=(k, len(cols)))
    for i in range(k):
        s = df.sample(frac=1, replace=True)[cols +[w]]
        for j, c in enumerate(cols):
            res[i, j] = np.average(s[c], weights=s[w], axis=0)
    return np.apply_along_axis(np.std, 0, res)
```

EDIT example:

```
test=pd.DataFrame({'w': [100, 500, 200, 1000, 300], 'x1': [1.15, 33, -18.2, 3.6, -3.3], 'x2': [22.9, -61.2, -11.2, 33.4, 13.8]})
bootstrap_se_mean(test, ['x1', 'x2'], 'w')
```

I also will have to run the function on slices of the data. It appears that df.sample has quite some overhead, so running it on 5000 rows takes about 1/6 of the time to run over 700k rows. Is there a way to improve this?